# "Sorry if I bother you" vs. "Sorry to bother you" : Which one is more idiomatic?

Tags: expression-choice

I need to send an message via SMS to my supervisor.

Which is more a idiomatic introduction?

> 1. "Sorry **if** I bother you."
> 2. "Sorry **if** I bother**ed** you."
> 3. "Sorry **to** bother you."

Comment: If it's an emergency SMS, then you should absolutely not worry about apologising at all. Your boss needs to know whatever it is. However, "which is more polite?" is **entirely** a matter of subjective opinion. A question "which is more idiomatic?" is less subjective because it can be backed up with (say) an Ngram graph or a dictionary example. Please edit the question to show what you have looked up and what you found.

Comment: @Andrew Leach , It's edited: "which one is more idiomatic ?" Thanks

Comment: You can't ask "Which is more polite" because it's opinion-based. Also, you can't ask more than one question. So the most-idiomatic one is the one to keep. Evidence of your own research would be beneficial.

Comment: @Andrew Leach , OK. Could you please answer to this one? "Which is more a idiomatic introduction?" Thanks.

Comment: "Sorry to bother you, but...," It's present tense because the message is doing the bothering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of question is easily answered by starting with [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Sorry+if+I+bother+you%2CSorry+if+I+bothered+you%2CSorry+to+bother+you%2CSorry+if+I+am+bothering&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSorry%20if%20I%20bothered%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSorry%20to%20bother%20you%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CSorry%20if%20I%20bothered%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSorry%20to%20bother%20you%3B%2Cc0). Here's the chart comparing

- Sorry if I bother you
- Sorry if I bothered you
- Sorry to bother you
- Sorry if I am bothering

Ngrams can only cope with phrases of up to five words, but missing *you* off the last one isn't going to change the result significantly, especially as that five-word phrase isn't found.

[image: Ngram]

**Sorry to bother you** is streets ahead of all the others, two of which don't appear at all.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than bother (don't presume that you are a bother,) how about using the word interrupt in its place and make it a statement, not a question?

"I don't mean to interrupt you. ..." Then get on with your message.

When someone asks "Can I ask you a question?" My first thought is "You just did" and my second thought is "if you'd have just asked it, this would be an answer to it right now."